# React state management rendering for one object or array of objects

Tags: reactjs, forms, rendering, use-state, react-state-management

I'm learning React and starting with handling state in a CRUD form via the `useState` Hook. Something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

where `data` is the object containing the state of the form and his props are the values of the inputs.

I have two concerns:

**1) Unnecessary rendering.**
If when an input is changed (onChange or onBlur event) I update the state, via a typical handleChanged function, for example:

```
const handleChanged = (e) => {
      setData(...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value)
});
```

does the form render only the specific changed input or the entire form (all inputs) ?  In case it was for all inputs, how could that be avoided?

**2) Arrays and useState.**
If instead of having a single data object I have an array of data objects, eg. in a editable table, how would the `useState` be handled for each array element? I have searched for examples but they are all for a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1:**

As per the following definition:
*React schedules a render every time the state of a component changes.*
`useState` changes only the component where change occurs.
In your case, I believe, the re-render occurs.

Why re-invent the wheel when it's already invented?

If you are concerned about forms, you should explore this library:
https://react-hook-form.com/

Also, you will be able to properly visualize it in the section *Isolate Re-renders* of https://react-hook-form.com/

**Part 2:**

You can use `useState` to store an `Array` and that `Array` can be a set of `Objects`.

In order to render components from the Array, you can further use `map` function.

Or if you want to simply access the data, then you can use index values to access objects.

I hope, this makes sense.

Explanation could have been better if the whole code snippet for your concerns was shared.

Regards,
Shameel Uddin